# How do I create a Time from a string in libgit2?

Tags: rust, libgit2

I'm trying to make a Git commit at a specific time. However, in [the Rust docs](https://docs.rs/git2/0.6.4/git2/struct.Time.html), I don't see an easy way to create a new `Time` object. In command line Git, I can set the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variable, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this, in-band or out-of-band, with libgit2.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, okay ... first you are at the older version of the libgit2 document. make sure you are looking at the latest version; here https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Time.html also, use chrono crate to convert between timestamp and the way libgit2 expects it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood your question, okay ... first you are at the older version of the libgit2 document. make sure you are looking at the latest version; here https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Time.html also, use chrono crate https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/ to convert between timestamp and the way libgit2 expects it using

Comment: This is more or less what I came up with. But I don't like it https://github.com/tkellogg/dura/blob/b604fd38b28d01682b848ee7eeda3fcf80e82c95/src/snapshots.rs#L68-L73

Comment: What do you not like about it? Assuming that you want libgit2 to be able to take the string internally and work with it.  The trouble with that is that parsing strings into time values is a complex process (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY for a great overview of the trouble we can run into hehehe) ... and because of that it should be its own whole library. This is specifically why libgit2 does NOT provide that functionality and just keeps its API to *unix time*

Comment: P.S. I think your approach is quite clean.

Comment: The documentation was a bit thin. I know I can't use just any `i64` for the timestamp, but it was a good bet it was a Unix timestamp given the association with Linus. Also, the offset is in minutes, and I had a nagging feeling in the back of my mind that there's gotchas in doing the conversion. I wish there was at least an example, or a stack overflow question...